# Huge variable visualization

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization

Just a quick one. I realized most of the ML processes and reports have some sort of visualization of the classes and the variables of the entire data. But I would like to ask if there's any way to visualize huge variables, say a data set of about 11,000 variables, and what types of visualization could be done?. And will it be able to give any useful information about the variables?

Comment: which kind of visualization do you want perform?

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: More importantly: what question are you trying to answer? The visualisation you choose ALWAYS depends on what message you want to deliver...